# Cpanel: no such user here

Tags: cpanel

Some people are receiving this error when trying to send a email to my domain. 
I have many domains in this vps with whm/cpanel, but only happes with this one and with some senders. I tried with hotmail and other business email and it doesn’t happen. But with other users that are trying to send to any email of our domain, it happens.

This is the error:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  nick@mydomain.com
    No Such User Here
Reporting-MTA: dns; single-4710.banahosting.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;nick@mydomain.com
Status: 5.0.0
Asunto  test
De  nick@elricodato.com
Destinatario    nick@mydomain.com
Fecha   Hoy 18:26
test
```

Comment: It sounds like a problem to take up with your hosting provider.

Comment: They didn’t help.

Comment: You can check the bounce back log in exim_rejectlog and make sure you have an appropriate setting in WHM>>Edit DNS for the localdomains and not in remotedomain. If you want to use the same cPanel email service, you should have localdomain selected. For a third party email service, it should be remotedomain selected.